# Checking luggage through from domestic flight (AA) to international flight (PAL) but separate tickets

Tags: transit, luggage

I am flying from Las Vegas via American Airlines to Los Angeles to connect to Philippine airlines. I have separate tickets. Can I check my luggage through to my final destination if the tickets are separately issued?

If they have have the same locator number with separate tickets, will that qualify for a checked through? Can the travel agency can do that?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this document from AA](https://saleslink.aa.com/en-us/documents/agencynews/through_checked_baggage_policy_06sep16.pdf):

> (...) when all the tickets are in the same PNR. Through check-in will be honored between the following carriers only:
>
> - American Airlines and American Eagle
> - oneworld airlines and affiliates

Philippine Airlines is not part of oneworld, so they will not do check-in to the final destination in this situation, even if the tickets were on the same PNR.

*(Note that this is in the case of multiple tickets — they would perform through check-in to a non-OW airline if all flights were on the same ticket).*

More details [here](https://saleslink.aa.com/en-us/documents/archives/agencyref/baggage-through_checked_baggage_policy-separate_tickets.pdf)